# Acrobat SDK on Standard vs Pro

Tags: adobe-acrobat, acrobat-pro-dc

I've been using a free trial of Adobe Acrobat Pro DC and now I'm looking to purchase it. What I'm questioning is whether I should buy the standard or pro version. I use the Acrobat SDK to automate a bunch of tasks including importing and exporting fields to and from databases, enabling and disabling fields' readonly property, and saving files as reader extended PDFs.

Does the standard version allow for all the same functionality as the pro version when using the SDK? I can't find the answer to this online and I don't want to purchase the standard version only to find out it doesn't provide all of the functionality that I need.

Another question I have is regarding the Perpetual license. I would preferably like to buy the Perpetual license as that will be the cheaper option in the long run. For the subscription license you can install the software on up to two computers. Is this the same for the Perpetual license? Or can the Perpetual license only be installed on one computer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of differences between Standard and Pro, the biggest around creation and management of PDF files.

This Adobe table provides a detailed table to help you with your specific needs.

https://www.content.shi.com/SHIcom/ContentAttachmentFiles/Adobe070915BrandPage/adc-comparison.html

I purchased a perpetual license for Adobe Standard V2017 and then switched to Adobe Pro DC Subscription. There have been 3 big upgrades since I purchased V2018 and now on V2020. So the subscription fits me well.

You need to compare and do what fits you best.

Comment: Thanks for your input John. Unfortunately that table does not mention too many specifics around creating forms, especially regarding the SDK. With the perpetual license could you only install it on one computer? Or did it work like the subscription where you could install it on two computers but only use it on one at a time.

Comment: Adobe SDK works with the version you have (https://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat.html#:~:text=The%20Acrobat%20DC%20SDK%20is,Adobe%20Acrobat%20DC%20SDK%20capabilities.) .  The licensing as far as I can see is to create PDF content which is free to users  (https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader/adobe-acrobat-dc-sdk-cost/td-p/8903038?page=1)